# Electromagnetic mass disproof

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

I've been reading the Feynman's lectures lately and found the section of electromagnetic mass in this article: https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_28.html (section 3 at this page). Here Feynman is talking about the mechanical and the electromagnetic momentum of mass, and the "possibility that the mechanical piece is not there at all—that the mass is all electromagnetic". Lower in the text follows an argumentation pointing against this assumption:

> for an arbitrary velocity $v$, the momentum is altered by the factor $1/\sqrt{1−v^2/c^2}$:
> $$ p=\frac{2}{3}  \frac{e^2}{(ac^2)}\frac{v} {\sqrt{1−v^2/c^2}}$$

and

> the field of the electron should have the mass
> $$m′_{elec}=\frac{U_{elec}}{c^2}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{e^2}{(ac^2)}$$
> which is not the same as the electromagnetic mass.

but I cannot quite understand how the given formulae actually prove the existence of "the mechanical piece" of mass, simply based on twisting of mathematical formulae. Can somebody put it into simpler **words** for me and help me understand it?

So, Q1: What is it that proves that the "mechanical mass" **is** there in deed?

And Q2: What part of the entire mass of an electron is non-electromagnetic, based on these formuli - is it 1/3, or 3/4 of the entire mass, and the rest is EMmass?

And on top of this - Q3:Why do the factors in the mentioned formuli change all the time - from $\frac{1}{2}$, to $\frac{2}{3}$, to $\frac{3}{4}$... (Excuse this too poor level of understanding of mine, but I will strongly appreciate some help!)

Comment: Please use MathJaX to format your equations;  it makes them much more readable.  Here is a [tutorial on how to do so.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  In addition, you might want to clarify the "factors" you're talking about in your last question;  not everyone has a copy of the Feynman lectures close at hand, and people will be more likely to answer if you provide more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feynman does not say that there must be mechanical mass, he explains that mass of a charged body cannot be purely electromagnetic, because something has to keep the charge concentrated on the body, and this something isn't electromagnetic force, so it has to be some non-electromagnetic force. This means there are non-electromagnetic contributions to energy and thus to mass.  The non-electromagnetic contribution can be negative or positive; in the case of the charged sphere held by non-EM forces, we expect it to be negative (attractive forces, negative energy in compact state).

Nobody knows how much of electron's mass is electromagnetic mass, because we do not know whether the electron is a charged sphere, and even if we assume it is, we do not know what the radius $a$ should be. Based on measurements of the electron g-factor there are estimates that electron radius is at most something like 1e-18 m and possibly much smaller.

This maximum possible radius combined with the charged sphere model imply much greater positive EM mass than observed, which then implies a negative non-electromagnetic mass that is much greater in magnitude than the observed mass. So in this "charged sphere model", two big contributions of opposite sign have to partially cancel each other and what remains is the observed mass. It is important model in EM theory, but its application to elementary particles brings mostly problems, and does not elucidate much. Electron is often thought of as point particle without structure.

The factors in different formulae are different because the formulae are for a different thing. Feynman's electromagnetic mass of a charged sphere is a different thing from the mass of EM energy of the charged sphere.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying all this for me in an understandable way, 
Ján Lalinský! As to this: "something has to keep the charge concentrated on the body, and this something isn't electromagnetic force, so it has to be some non-electromagnetic force." - is it already confirmed what exactly it is? Can it not be that quanta themselves keep the charge concentrated, i.e. quanta themselves **are** a charged concentrated body? Or has that assupmpion already been ruled out by quantum mechanics and/or theoretical physics? (Also, thank you for helping out with the formatting)

Comment: The model of charged extended body where the charge is held in place by some additional force belongs mostly to macroscopic EM theory, even though it started as model of electron. It wasn't very fruitful for our understanding of elementary particles such as electron or proton. We do not know what holds the charge together in elementary particles. In case of proton, there is internal structure and nuclear forces play role. In case of electron, no structure is known; maybe it is indivisible and thus no "Poincare stresses" are needed to keep it together; if it has no parts, there is no repulsion.

Comment: Quantization of EM field or other fields does not seem to immediately explain how extended charged body can keep in a compact state despite the Coulombic repulsion between parts. On the other hand, in QT e.g. Schroedinger's equation sort of does describe how psi function of an atom does not expand into infinity and does not decay down to zero everywhere. But it does this for psi function or for probability density of point particles, not for charge density of a continuous charge.

Comment: Thank you for educating me so well, Ján Lalinský! As I understand it, QM prefers to work and do research viewing all particles as a sort of, namely, point particles - rather for simplification. Do you happen to know any relevant literature that explains quantum phenomena in terms of continuous charges/entities, not as point particles? Feynamn does so in a way, too, but are there more authors?

Comment: Well that is how the classical EM field theory or quantum field theory looks on this. In these theories, because they are theories of *field*, electronic charge is not necessarily concentrated into points (this causes difficulties in field theories), but is more like a fuzzy cloud in space, so there is not always a definite number of "charged particles". This is also a big drawback of these theories, since we do observe charged particles with elementary charge $e$ or its whole multiples, but never fractions of $e$.

Answer (score 2):

Feynman is using the notation $a$ for the radius of the electron. The first point he makes, in section 28-1, is that this is infinite for a point charge. You could basically stop reading there. Current theory treats electrons as pointlike particles, so this infinite mass is a problem. For example, we see processes that create electron-positron pairs, which would be impossible if they had infinite mass-energy. The problem is really a problem with classical physics. We need quantum mechanics instead.

But Feynman is developing the absurd consequences that you arrive at when you know relativity, don't know about quantum mechanics, and try to develop a theory of electrons that have finite radius. This is the sort of thing that people would have tried to do ca. 1905-1927. The fact that you're confused by all the fractions like 3/4, etc., is because he's showing how silly it gets when you try to develop the theory in this way, and also because he follows the kind of complications that people tried to introduce to salvage the idea of point charges in classical physics. None of it actually ends up working out. E.g., you get equations for the motion of point charges (28-5) that have unphysical properties like the fact that charges accelerate before the time when a force is applied to them.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question is asking about the analysis of the charged sphere model and electromagnetic mass, not asking for reasons to "stop reading there". Feynman explains the motivations and importance of the topic well. *"However, when electromagnetism is joined to quantum mechanics, the difficulties remain. So it will not be a waste of our time now to look at what these difficulties are. Also, they are of great historical importance. "*

Comment: fjkdfjh :) Can you further explain to me why an electrons cannot have infinite mass? As I understand it, some part of the electron's mass is EM mass. The EM energy constituting a quant, what also the electron is, is not "frozen" within the electron, but "actively moving", as this is a "property" of the EM energy, so the EM part of the electron should, at least theoretically, also be infinite -wave alike, may be attenuating though. The electron-positron pairs should still be possible even with an infinite radius, simply forming a new entity with an infinite radius - the  electron-positron pair.

Comment: And just to add up - the language in this answer is the kind of language that I understand and use, so if you could continue writing like this it will be highly appreciated!